# ASP.NET MVC - JSON response sends me a file instead of updating the jqueryUI

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm returning a json data, and I can confirm that it is bringing data back to client. but instead of updating my jqueryaccordion, it asks me to save or open the file. Below is my script and controller. I have used jquery modal dialog to edit the employee details through a partial view, and clicking on update button should update the respective employee in the accordion list.Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks

**Update**

When debugging through IE tools, I noticed that when the 'update' button is clicked, the 'initiator' in the 'request' tab shows 'click'. I am guessing this should be 'XMLHttpRequest' Instead. Hope this information helps. Thanks

**Main View**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Employee", "EditEmployees", "Home",
                        new { id = item.Id }
                        , new { @class = "editLink" })
```

**Partial View with Edit Employee Form - EditEmployee.cshtml**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditEmployees", "Home", new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
        }, new { @id = "updateEmployeeForm" }))
    {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Action Result that returns partial view containing the editemployee form**

```
Public ActionResult EditEmployee(int id)
{
//DataAccess part
return PartialView("EditEmployee",employeedata);
}
```

**Controller that returns Json Result after updating the employee details**

```
[HttpPost]
Public JsonResult EditEmployee(Models.Employee employee)  
{  
       //Data access part

     JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
                            result.Data = employeeData;
                            return result;
}
```

**Script on Main View**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            var linkObj;
            $(function () {
                $(".editLink").button();

            $('#updateDialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Update": function () {
                        $("#update-message").html(''); 
                        $("#updateEmployeeForm").submit();
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $(".editLink").click(function () {
                //change the title of the dialog
                linkObj = $(this);
                var dialogDiv = $('#updateDialog');
                var viewUrl = linkObj.attr('href');
                $.get(viewUrl, function (data) {
                    dialogDiv.html(data);

                    var $form = $("#updateEmployeeForm");
                    // Unbind existing validation
                    $form.unbind();     
                               dialogDiv.dialog('open');
                });
                return false;
            });

        });

 function updateSuccess(data) {
 // I want to make sure that this function gets executed on Success instead of a file being sent back to me from the server
  $('#updateDialog').dialog('close');
  $('#commonMessage').html("Update Complete");
  $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(3000).slideUp(400);
  alert("hello");

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get(viewUrl, function (data) {
```

If this is how you get your `ajax` data, I can say, that this server code return error:

```
JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
    result.Data = employeeData;
    return result;
```

because by default `JsonResult` allow only `POST` requests

As solution you can use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

Comment: I'm actually performing a post operation to the controller from the form. So I don't think, I need AlloGet. I am thinking it has something to do with my scripts. I have done F12, and I could see the data JSON is bringing back. All good and 200.!!.any help ? thanks

Comment: @Jundev You trying to update UI after form submit (with page refresh) with json?

Comment: No, I would like to close the UI Dialog, and update the employee details in the main view's accordion. Well, I would be happy even if the alert box appears, so I would know that the 'updateSuccess' function gets called. I've updated my question as well. Thanks

Comment: @Jundev Ok, now your code looks readable. What I can see: `Ajax.BeginForm` doesn't have `UpdateTargetId = "your_result_id"`, than I can't find where you calling `EditEmployee` (links and form use `EditEmployees`)

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem I have right now. I just want to make sure that the 'updateSuccess' function in main view gets updated 'onSuccess' instead of a file being sent back. I know the JSON response is a success because I get a 200, and I could see the data being brought back as well. I've updated my code and question and have provided few more details. Thanks

Comment: @Jundev Ok, both actions use `EditEmployee`, but link and form calls `EditEmployees` (with 'S'). You trying to return `json`, remove `InsertionMode` and print your results.

Comment: @Jundev Also, it could be problem with this code: `$form.unbind();`. Which could remove some mvc ajax `events` from form. `Fiddler` will answer on all questions ;)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, 'EditEmployee' is spelt correctly in the code. All right, if $form.unbind() is causing the issue, are there any alternatives ? I've only used the method Ricardo Covo has used. The demo app I downloaded from his site works perfectly, but I'm not sure why mine doesn't work. here's the link to his site. Please see if you can help- thanks http://ricardocovo.com/2012/04/06/asp-mvc3-editing-records-with-jqueryui-dialogs-and-ajaxforms-razor-version/

Comment: @Jundev I think you should also check javascript includes. `~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` from `_layout.cshtml`. His example works with `unbind` and without it. I am not microsoft ajax fun, so I am using `Html.BeginForm` and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late but ... adding the jquery unobtrusive reference to my view fixed the issue.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: in fact this is better solution.